# Incomplete boot, but not every time

Tags: boot, grub2

I have an old PC with 12.04 LTS on it, used headless for NAS.  It's set in the BIOS to boot on AC application and grub2 is set to continue after a 10 second wait time.

Every "X" number of boots (less than 10% of the time), the boot process hangs after the grub countdown finishes and a blank screen appears.  There is no hard drive activity.

The odd thing is that if I then press the power switch on the PC, it shuts off, and if I press the power switch again, the grub screen comes up with 1 second remaining (instead of the normal 10 seconds), and the boot proceeds normally.

I'd really appreciate suggestions on how to track this down.  What logs can I look at?

It's especially perplexing that it only happens every now and then.

Comment: If I have no clue where to start, I look at `/var/log/kern.log.1` `dmesg.0` and `syslog.1`. So that would be a good place to start as these show the *previous* boot logs. Post these to http://paste.ubuntu.com next time this happens and post a comment @Fabby below.

Comment: Thanks, will do.  I also turned 'quiet splash' off in grub so that if it hangs next time, I can see the last message.

Comment: This turned out to be the 'press S to skip' message, but I couldn't see it because the sever was running headless.  I'm trying the nobootwait fix and marking this question as a duplicate. Thanks again, @Fabby.